# trying to work classes together

Tags: java

I'm looking into learning java and i have a little problem with the code.

so i have this class called apples defining 3 strings

```
public class apples {

    public static String a,b,c;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        a = "its an a";
        b = "its an b";
        c = "its an c";

    }
    public void printit(){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}
```

and then i have this classed callled workingWith2NDclass which should be working along with the apples class

```
public class workingWith2NDclass {
    public static void main(){
        apples aMethod = new apples();
        aMethod.printit();
    }
}
```

what i'm trying to do is to see how class works together but somewhat the line that calls the printit function wont work, why is that?

Comment: You're probably executing `apples.main` instead of `workingWith2NDclass.main`.

Comment: What's the expected output, and what you're obtaining?

Comment: How do you run the program? What does "won't work" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, please post it.

Comment: p.s. In Java, it is common to start class names with upper case letters.

Comment: I suggest that you learn about two topics: 1) constructors and 2) the difference between static and non-static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have the rep to comment on a sub-post, but you have an error here:

```
public class workingWith2NDclass {
    public static void main(){
        apples aMethod = new apples();
        aMethod.printit();
    }
}
```

You should have 'String[] args' as an argument in the entry method. These are the args specified when your program is started via the command line.

```
public class workingWith2NDclass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        apples aMethod = new apples();
        aMethod.printit();
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the use of the args? what does it mean and what its purpose?

Comment: The String[] are the args that you would use to start your program via the command line. If you packaged your program into a jar, you could do something like this to start it via command line: `java -jar TestProgram.jar apples cookies turtles` The String[] would now look like ['apples', 'cookies', 'turtles'].

Answer (score 1):

The main method in workingWith2NDclass does not call the main method in the apples class. Because of this, when the printit() method is called, a, b, and c are not initialized (i.e. they have no value).

I think what you want is to use a *contructor* method as follows:

```
public class apples {
    public static String a,b,c;
    // This method contructs the appls class, to be used by others. It initializes the a, b, and c members.
    public apples(){
        a = "its an a";
        b = "its an b";
        c = "its an c";
    }
    public void printit(){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

When you run a java program, only one main method (that of the entry class) is called. That means that, because apples does not have a main method, you have to call the one in workingWith2NDclass.

So you now compile your program as

```
javac workingWith2NDclass.java
```

and run it with

```
java workingWith2NDclass
```

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class learnJava.apples, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)